# JQuery How do I make part of a form highlighted when focused?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form which is divided into parts seperated by divs eg:

```
<form>
<div>
   Account Details
</div>
<div>
Personal Details
</div>
<div>
...etctec
</div>

</form>
```

I want that when someone highlights or focuses on any element within the divs the div in question is highlighted using css. Consider the fact that I have applied a number of handlers to certain input elements on this form.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
$('input').focus(
    function(){
        // adds the 'highlight' class to the parent
        $(this).closest('div').addClass('highlight');
    });
```

With:

```
$('input').blur(
    function(){
        // removes the 'highlight' class from the parent so only one highlight is ever visible.
        $(this).closest('div').removeClass('highlight');
    });
```

And define the `highlight` class in CSS:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VBDrJ/), please note that, in the demo, I use `fieldset`s rather than `div` to wrap the various `label` and `input` elements, but otherwise it's exactly the same principle.

Updated the demo for increased prettiness: [Revised JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VBDrJ/1/).

---

**Edited** in response to question from OP:

> Thats great - however theres a little problem with this code i.e that if ever an input within a div loses focus the div is shown as unhighlighted. Is there a way so that a div remains focus until an input element in another div is focused upon which the parent of the focused div would then get highlighted

Yeah, assuming that I've understood you right, that's pretty easy:

```
$('input').focus(
    function() {
        $(this)
            .closest('form')
            .find('.highlight')
            .removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).closest('fieldset').addClass('highlight');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VBDrJ/2/).

Comment: Thats great - however theres a little problem with this code i.e that if ever an input within a div loses focus the div is shown as unhighlighted. Is there a way so that a div remains focus until an input element in another div is focused upon which the parent of the focused div would then get highlighted

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form > div').delegate('input', 'focus', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').addClass('active');
}).delegate('input', 'blur', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').removeClass('active');    
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/fG8Au/

If you want to be sure that only the div right inside the form tag is highlighted, use `$(this).closest('form > div')`.

Comment: Thats neat - how can I amend it so that if I click within the div, it doesn't loose focus..currently if I click within the div focus is lost from teh input and the containing div loses the class assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Create a highlight class in your CSS and try the following jQuery:

```
$('input, select, textarea').focus (function ()
{
    var elem = $(this), container = elem.parents ('div');

    container.siblings ().removeClass ('highlight');
    container.addClass ('highlight');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.highlight{background:#ddd}


$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('div.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).parent().addClass('highlight');
});
```